# HTTP Error code from TransferJob under KDE (KIO)

Tags: linux, qt, kde-plasma

I'm launching HTTP GET job under KDE 5 with
`job = KIO::get(url, KIO::NoReload, KIO::HideProgressInfo);`

in slot connected to `KIO::TransferJob::result` i'm getting `job->error()` equal to 0, but `KIO::TransferJob::isErrorPage()` equal to `true`. And `data` containing something like:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

As I understand - slave http job indicates that the page is an error page but the code of this error isn't forwarded to parent job or I couldn't find a way to get it. I would like to get the code (403) without parsing the received data. Is that possible?

https://httpstat.us/403 may be used for tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is yes you can.
The only option is `TransferJob::isErrorPage()` to know if any error happened. As per this line of code in `transferjob.cpp`

```
     q->connect(slave, &SlaveInterface::errorPage, q, [this]() {
         m_errorPage = true;
     });
```

But if you look at `http.cpp` in *ioslaves*, you will find that meta data with key value of ***responsecode*** is added to `Job::metaData` so you can query that value like this:

```
auto httpResponseCode = job->metaData().value(QStringLiteral("responsecode"));
```

`httpResponseCode` would be a `QString` because `KIO::MetaData` is actually a `QMap<QString,QString>` type.

Comment: You're right. `metaData().value(QStringLiteral("responsecode"))` works

Comment: I'll be able to award a bounty in 17 hours.

Comment: @turf, it is ok.